# Transform an Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I  have a simple problem that I can't solve:

```
const array = [0, 1, 2]
```

output:

```
[ [0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1], [1, 2], [0, 2], [2] ]
```

As you can see my output contain arrays with all possibilities of the first array. How can I do that?

Comment: there should be examples of how to do this, it is combinations C of N selectoins where N ranges from 1...Length(array), concatenated together

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075180/combinations-of-size-n-from-an-array