# Algolia query by INTERSECTION COUNT with two lists

Tags: algolia

I need to query some users based on "similar" interests. If a user A has 2 similar interests as user B then it's a match. I want to know if the following query is possible in Algolia.

Lets say I have two objects in some Algolia index with a list property on them (interests):

```
obj1 = {
    interests: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
}
obj2 = {
    interests: ['B', 'C', 'D'],
}
```

And I want to query all objects with `interests` having at least 2 of the following:

```
interests: ['A', 'B', 'E']
```

This should return me just `obj1` since is the one having 2 interests alike.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of an easier way to do this. But let me show my findings
`interests: ['A', 'B', 'E']`

now to capture your requirement the `filters` statement should be something like
**`'(interests:A AND interests:B) OR (interests:A AND interests:E) OR (interests:B AND interests:E)'`**
which if take as a boolean expression is in the form of **`AB+AC+BC`**.

But this particular query **cannot** be used with algolia according to their [docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/filters/)

> **For performance reasons, we do not support the following boolean combinations:**
> ...
>
> We limit filter expressions to a conjunction (ANDs) of disjunctions
> (ORs). For example you can use `filter1 AND (filter2 OR filter3)`), but
> not ORs of ANDs (e.g. `filter1 OR (filter2 AND filter3)`.

But we can convert the `AB+AC+BC` to a product of sum format. I used https://www.dcode.fr/boolean-expressions-calculator and obtained the equivalent
**`(A+B).(A+C).(B+C)`** which would then be

**`'(interests:A OR interests:B) AND (interests:A OR interests:E) AND (interests:B OR interests:E)'`**

The  query also depends on how many elements are there in the `interests` array. For example if `interests: ['A', 'E', 'C', 'F']` your final filter query would look in the form
**`'(interests:A OR interests:E OR interests:C) AND (interests:A OR interests:E OR interests:F) AND (interests:A OR interests:C OR interests:F) AND (interests:E OR interests:C OR interests:F)'`**

Individual product terms have `length of interest array-1` terms

**TLDR:** **`'(interests:A OR interests:B) AND (interests:A OR interests:E) AND (interests:B OR interests:E)'`**

you can use a use a combination generating code and get the filter query.
Here is a JS example based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075180/combinations-of-size-n-from-an-array).

```js
const k_combinations = (set, k) => {
    let i, j, combs, head, tailcombs;
    if (k > set.length || k <= 0) {
        return [];
    }
    if (k == set.length) {
        return [set];
    }
    if (k == 1) {
        combs = [];
        for (i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
            combs.push([set[i]]);
        }
        return combs;
    }
    combs = [];
    for (i = 0; i < set.length - k + 1; i++) {
        head = set.slice(i, i+1);
        tailcombs = k_combinations(set.slice(i + 1), k - 1);
        for (j = 0; j < tailcombs.length; j++) {
            combs.push(head.concat(tailcombs[j]));
        }
    }
    return combs;
}
const combinations = (set) => {
    let k, i, combs, k_combs;
    combs = [];
    for (k = 1; k <= set.length; k++) {
        k_combs = k_combinations(set, k);
        for (i = 0; i < k_combs.length; i++) {
            combs.push(k_combs[i]);
        }
    }
    return combs;
}
    
const generateFilterQuery = (array) => {
  const combinationSize  = array.length - 1
  const combinations = k_combinations(array, combinationSize)
  return combinations.map((comb) => `(${comb.map(c => `interests:${c}`).join(" OR ")})`).join(" AND ")
}


console.log(generateFilterQuery(["A","B","E"]))
console.log(generateFilterQuery(["A","B","C","D"]))
console.log(generateFilterQuery(["A","B","C","D","E"]))
```

After generating the filter query pass it as the value of `filters` parameter

```js
index.search('',{
    filters: generatedQuery
}
).then(({hits}) => console.log(hits))
```

Comment: This is so helpful! Appreciate it :)